# Laravel REST Api as Server Push over HTTP2

Tags: php, laravel, api, http2

I am currently using laravel as my backend with a API built for android client 
thats consumes the api.

I have configured websockets with PUSHER to handle new changes on server to be pushed to subscribed clients to avoid a server polling.

But sometimes the client need to go to server to get initial data from multiple endpoints or more than one image resources.

I have found the two libraries for laravel that help in implementing web side of laravel HTTP2 complaint

1 -> https://github.com/tomschlick/laravel-http2-server-push

2 -> https://github.com/JacobBennett/laravel-HTTP2ServerPush

from this link https://laravel-news.com/http2-server-push-middleware

So the question is it possible to implement HTTP2 on REST API endpoint where the client need to hit multiple url subsequently.

One solution can to inlucde all the resources in a single response, but that can be done only if all the responses are JSON.

How can I push json along with some small images.